# Creating multiple async pipes of unknown number

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, async.js, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am using Angular 5 and loading a list of items using a selector with my NGRX library. My selector returs a list of items which I used to dynamically create tabs on a page using the async pipe. Now, when a user clicks on a tab, I want to fire off another selector to go fetch data from my NGRX store, which may or may not exist, ad could trigger an API request in the effect and updated by the reducer. All that works fine.

My issue is, I have a variable number of tabs, which could potentially trigger multiple async requests, and I want to bind the response to each of these requests to the right tab. I'm not sure how to do that? 
I have my code like this:

this.store$
            .select(getTabContent(id)).pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$), take(1)).subscribe((data) => { ...};

but would rather use an async pipe, and I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it using the reactive library. How can I create variable async pipes and be able to bind to specific tabs in my case?

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to share somewhere ids of tabs and then you can use switchMap and combineLatest to get notifications of all tabs.

```js
ids$ = new BehaviorSubject([1, 2, 3]); // initial tabs

ngOnInit() {
  this.tabs$ = ids$.pipe(
    // creates an array of selectors
    switchMap(ids => combineLatest(ids.map(id => this.store.select(getTabContent(id))))),
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
  );
}

addTab() {
  this.ids$.next([...this.ids$.value, 4]);
}
```

and in the template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="tabs$ | async as tabs">
  <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">{{ tab | json }}</tab>
</ng-container>
<a (click)="addTab()">Add Tab</a>
```